# Kivy recycleview duplicating data items

Tags: python-3.x, kivy

I have a recycle view in kivy im writing to it with a list containing text and images, the text is fine but as soon as i write an image its duplicating the image in the view as i scroll down please see code below, how would i stop this from happening, here is my kv file I have a boxlayout with two sets of data, heres a picture of the problem as well[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/seU7R.jpg)

```
kv file:

 <SelectableReportTextbox@BoxLayout>:


    text: ''
    imagesource: ''
    color: ''


    Button:
            size_hint:  .8, 1
            text_size : self.text_size
            size_hint_y: None
            foreground_color: [1, 1, 1, 1]
            background_color: (0.2, 0.4, 0.8, 0.9) # root.color
            font_name: 'C:\kivy_venv\Graphics\GIL_____.TTF'
            font_size: self.height*0.2
            background_normal: root.imagesource
            text: root.text





  ScreenTwo:

    rv2: rv2


    canvas.before:


            Rectangle:
                    size:self.size           #100, 100
                    pos: self.pos
                    source: "C:\kivy_venv\Graphics\Jetfireback.png" 



    RecycleView_B:


            bar_width: 6
            size_hint: (None, None)
            do_scroll_y: True
            id: scrlv2
            size: (500, 500)
            pos_hint: {'center_x': .75, 'center_y': .64}
            multiline:True



            ProjectRV:


                    viewclass: 'SelectableReportTextbox'        #  
                    orientation: "horizontal"
                    scroll_type: ['bars', 'content']
                    scroll_wheel_distance: dp(114)
                    key_size: "height"

                    padding:1, 1
                    space_x: self.size[0]/3
                    id: rv2
                    pos_hint: {'center_x': 0.32, 'center_y': 0.525}
                    bar_width: dp(25)
                    bar_color: (0.7, 0.1, 0.3, 0.7)
                    bar_inactive_color: (0.1, 0.1, 0.1 , 1)
                    scroll_y : 0



                    SelectableRecycleBoxLayout:
                            rv2:rv2

                            spacing : '6'
                            default_size_hint: 1, None
                            size_hint_y: None
                            size_hint_x: 1

                            height: self.minimum_height
                            multiselect: True
                            touch_multiselect: True
                            orientation: 'vertical'
```

main.py:

```
class SelectableRecycleBoxLayout(FocusBehavior,LayoutSelectionBehavior,RecycleBoxLayout):   
''' Adds selection and focus behaviour to the view. '''



 class SelectableReportTextbox(RecycleDataViewBehavior):
        selectable = BooleanProperty(True)
        index =None

        selected = BooleanProperty(False)
def __init__(self, **kw):
    super().__init__(**kw)
def refresh_view_attrs(self, rv, index, data):

    ''' Catch and handle the view changes '''
    self.index = index
    return super(SelectableRecycleBoxLayout, self).refresh_view_attrs(
        rv, index, data)


class ProjectRV(RecycleView):


def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    super(ProjectRV, self).__init__(**kwargs)




 class RecycleView_B(RecycleView):

      pass

  class ScreenTwo(Screen):

        TEXT_FILE = open("output.txt", "a")

        zdata = re.search('{.*,', strdata).group(0)   
        splitex = zdata.split(':' + "'")[1]

        print (zdata)

        TEXT_FILE.write(zdata)

        TEXT_FILE.close()

        with open("output.txt", "r") as f:

           txtdata = eval(str('[' + ''.join(f.readlines()) + ']'))#ast.literal_eval

           nstring = type(txtdata)

           self.rv2.data = txtdata
           self.rv2.refresh_from_viewport()
           self.rv2.refresh_from_data()
```

Comment: Can't tell what is going on without seeing the python code. Please post a [mcve]. The one issue I see in the `kv` is that the `SelectableReportTextbox@BoxLayout:` at the top of the `kv` file should be a rule (enclosed in `<>`).

Comment: I added the python code where im writing to recycleview, basically i just get a message from the server convert to list format and write to the text file if its an image it will also be written to the same file with image in the the list instead of text

Comment: Your `kv` defines a `ScreenTwo` that contains a `RecycleView` (`RecycleView_B`) that contains another `RecycleView` (`ProjectRV`). Is that your intention? Please do a `print(txtdata)` and show us the results.

Comment: I tried removing the one recycleview it had no affect on the problem i printed txtdata this is what format it is [{'imagesource': 'contacts.png'}, {'text': 'test'}, {'text': 'test'}, {'text': 'test'}, {'text': 'test'},

Answer (score 1):

The `RecycleView` re-uses `viewclass` object instances, and sets properties of those instances based on the `data` dictionaries. So, if one of your dictionaries sets the `imagesource` property of a `viewclsas` instance and then that instance is re-used for a dictionary that does not set the `imagesource` property, then that instance will retain that prior value of `imagesource`. The fix is to make sure that every dictionary in the `data` contains a value for every property of the `viewclass`. Each dictionary needs to include values for `text`, `imagesource`, and `color`, even if the value is `''`.

Comment: thanks John for making that clear, that makes sense now